# Como verifcar se um trigger existe ou não antes de cria-lo?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, trigger

Pretendo criar um **trigger** na **tabela_X** mas antes gostaria de verificar se ela ja existe na minha base .... como faço ?

`CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS before_update_tableX ... ect`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Consultando os *triggers*

Depende do que você chama de "saber se existe". Saber se existe o nome, ou o conteúdo?

Para uma "espiada" basta o

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

Agora, se precisar de algo mais elaborado:

```
SELECT
   trigger_schema,
   trigger_name,
   action_statement
FROM
   information_schema.triggers

-- aqui vc cria sua condicao se quiser --
WHERE
   trigger_name = "batatas"
```

### Ao criar o *trigger*

De acordo com o manual

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html

não há um meio especifico de condicionar a criação à existência ou não, mas também não há riscos de se criar dois *triggers* com o mesmo nome, simplesmente você terá um retorno de erro ao tentar.

Aí seria só o caso de checar o retorno. Se falhou, terá o código de erro indicando o motivo (e pelo código pode determinar se a falha foi pelo fato de o *trigger* já existir).

> Erro 1359 - O trigger já existe
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_trg_already_exists

Se você quer só evitar um retorno de erro, tem como fazer o contrário do que você pediu. Remover o *trigger* existente, e criar novamente:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tres_pratos_de_trigo;

DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER tres_pratos_de_trigo
... etc ...
```

**Mas atenção**, neste caso é o oposto do que foi pedido. O *trigger* antigo será eliminado, e só valerá o novo.

Comment: preciso simplesmente saber se o nome ja existe ... !

Comment: @AndréPKA o show triggers já basta então.

Comment: eu tenho un script que criar o **trigger x** si o trigger **x** existe não cria, se não existe então cria !

Comment: Isso não foi perguntado, foi perguntado como saber se existe antes de inserir (e é o que eu respondi). Se quer saber como fazer para criar só se não existir, é outra pergunta. Posso até complementar a resposta, mas lembre-se de sempre que perguntar, especificar com exatidão o que quer.

Comment: você esta certo, farei isso na proxima... !!

Comment: @AndréPKA de qq forma, vou complementar a resposta jajá

Comment: Valeu... Mas pode deixar a versao antiga da resposta ai também!

Comment: @AndréPKA deixei, e complementei. Veja se assim resolve. Preciso dar uma saída, mas qq coisa deixe um comment que eu reviso aqui depois.